# linear layout not filling parent down the remaining part of the screen in a scrollview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am designing a layout for an activity where some contents like Textview, spinner and buttons are arranged in the upper part of the screen. I want to position image view to the bottom of the screen with a match_parent attribute to fill to the remaining bottom of the screen and it has become a challenge to me as the image view is filling to the bottom of the remaining part of the screen. This is the entire layout of the upper section/part of the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


  <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
     android:background="@drawable/xxxVal"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/dataVaues"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
  <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinBundle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="6sp"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:prompt="@string/_prompt" />

  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Plan" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/bundle"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#000"/>  

    <!-- android:inputType="phone"  -->

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="PValue:" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:inputType="value"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000"/>  

<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/validValue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Valid:"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/valid"
    android:inputType="valid"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
  <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/proceed"
    android:text="Proceed"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#000"/>

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:text="Check"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

this is remaining part of the layout with a view flipper for an image that I want it to fit down to the remaining part of the screen but its not fitting as it shrinks up

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
      <ViewFlipper
                    android:id="@+id/flipper1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:flipInterval="5000"
                    android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_in_right"
                    android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_out_left" >
                </ViewFlipper>
            </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

please kindly assist!

Comment: Can you also post the image of it

Comment: I think the Imageview will follow the dimensions of the Image and not the layout, so if th Image doesn't fill out the screen naturally, the Imageview will also not fill out the screen.

Comment: it does naturally

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the imageview to the Viewflipper like so:

```
<ViewFlipper
android:id="@+id/simpleViewFlipper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src=IMAGE />
</ ViewFlipper >
```

Having said that you might find some issues regarding swiping when using a viewflipper inside a scrollview

Comment: this has been taken care of in the code >>>> flipper.addView(imageView);

Comment: because it happens dynamicly it's making problems in the viewflipper , if you don't want to change that you can also give the viewflipper a fixed height if all the images are the same height

Comment: all the images are not thesame height have tried this your approach and its still the same result